# How to fix Incorrect syntax near the keyword "NOT" during Update-Database using Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new into software development. I am currently developing Asp.Net Core API. I have managed to do Add-migration successfully, the problem start when I need to Update-Database.

The error is as follows

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:9cf19409-67c7-4553-b2f9-5407db27d008
Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.
```

Your assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a providing a stack dump and no source code is not helpful.

Comment: Can you provide a code where you got an error? It's hard to give a solution. kindly check your query syntax?

Answer (score 9):

As highlighted by [YogeshJadadhav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579392/9239659), you might need to check your auto generated file for errors. Note that the error might not be highlighted by the debugger because its not a syntax error, but rather a string error. Here is a snippet of code showing how I resolved this issue.

**Auto generated code with error**

```
 Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18, 2", nullable: false)
```

**Corrected Code**

```
 Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18, 2)", nullable: false)
```

You will have to ractify this error in your *migrationName.cs and migrationName.Designer.cs*.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue in initial migration to create database.
The PMC console throw " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'. " error.
after debugging couple of minutes i found in the 
.HasColumnType("varchar(3"); attribute for one of the field.
It seems that during migration one bracket was lost in auto generated migration file - it looked like this "HasColumnType("varchar(3") instead it should look like this HasColumnType("varchar(3)") like this.

**I found this in "/Migrations/..ModelSnapshot.cs", in both, "Up" and "Down"methods.
and "/Migrations/..20190613110239_InitialCreate"**

After adding bracket in this two places the Update-Database command works as intended.

I hope it will help! Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: The reason is mostly because you've done syntactic error in your model class which is to be inserted as a table in database.

Solution:

1. You can remove the last migration, edit the model class , create a new migration and update the database.
2. You can edit the migration file correctly

Example:
This was my mistake firstly in model class
 `[Column(TypeName ="decimal(18,2")] public decimal Price { get; set; }` The missing first bracket in "decimal(18,2".
Then I deleted the previous migration , added first bracket, created new migration and updated database.
It worked just fine.